# mysql results with some encrypted data

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

Is it possible to get the results of a query and decrypt one column?

For example:

```
name | username | date     | password
ted  | teddy01  | 01/01/13 | s4drcfgbh76
```

So I want the results of this column (above) and it's all regular text apart from the password which is AES_ENCRYPTED.

Comment: Are you storing plaintext passwords?

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/20/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/

Comment: what is the encryption algorithm you are using when you store the password?

Comment: All entries are regular text apart from the password which is encrypted using Aes_encrypt()

Comment: You never want to store passwords using 2-way encryption.  You have to realize that means someone can just find your key and get all plaintext passwords.  Use a 1-way hash (SHA1 or MD5 for example), that way nobody can easily (that's up for debate, I know) get passwords from your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already left a comment saying why this is a bad way to store passwords, but since I hate when people just answer with, "don't do that," I figured I would tell you how to do it for different instances.

In MySQL you can call [AES_DECRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt).

A sample query would be:

```
SELECT username, created_date, AES_DECRYPT(encrypted_column_data,key) AS decrypted_data
FROM table
WHERE username = '$username'
```

This will give you results like:

```
username    | created_date | decrypted_data
Mitnosirrag | 2012-02-03   | "here is an unencrypted string"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after thanks, I wouldn't normally need to decrypt the password nor want to but its for in house admin system. Reading your response makes sense thanks again.